# Ordering of categorical data labels from pandas dataframe in plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have data in the following format, where the column stage was created by
`df['stage'] = pd.Categorical(df['stage'], categories=['Undef', 'C', 'A', 'B'], ordered=True)`, to create an ordering as follows: `Undef < C < A < B`. When I `print(df['stage'])`, this ordering is confirmed.

```
     stage                time
0    A     2012-01-26 21:52:56
1    A     2012-01-26 21:53:26
2    A     2012-01-26 21:53:56
3    A     2012-01-26 21:54:26
4    A     2012-01-26 21:54:56
..   ...                 ...
953  B     2012-01-27 05:49:26
954  B     2012-01-27 05:49:56
955  B     2012-01-27 05:50:26
956  C     2012-01-27 05:50:56
957  Undef 2012-01-27 05:51:26
```

This is how I plot the data:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.time, df.stage)
plt.show()
```

The stages should be on the y axis and have the specified ordering, but they just appear in the ordering of their first appearance in the dataframe.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: This is what the plot currently looks like:
[image]

All I want to do is to change the order of the y-labels to a custom order (and of course the corresponding plotted values).

Edit2: When adding the line `df.sort_values(['stage'], inplace=True)` this is what happens to the plot - which cannot be accurate as there can only be one stage at a time (although the ylabels are in the correct order now)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the code to do what you are looking for. As the dates are in the x-axis, you will need to convert the labels to integers and back. So, first the dictionary is defined to show mapping of Undef, A, B, C as per your requirement. A list with the converted values is created and plot drawn. Finally, the updated y-axis ticklabels are done...

**My data (input)**

```
stage   time
0   A   2012-01-26 21:52:56
1   A   2012-01-26 21:53:26
2   A   2012-01-26 21:53:56
3   A   2012-01-26 21:54:26
4   A   2012-01-26 21:55:56
5   B   2012-01-26 21:56:56
6   B   2012-01-26 21:57:56
7   B   2012-01-26 21:58:56
8   B   2012-01-26 21:59:56
9   B   2012-01-26 22:00:56
10  C   2012-01-26 22:01:56
11  C   2012-01-26 22:02:56
12  C   2012-01-26 22:03:56
13  C   2012-01-26 22:04:56
14  Undef   2012-01-26 22:05:56
15  Undef   2012-01-26 22:06:56
16  Undef   2012-01-26 22:07:56
```

**Plot without any sorting (your code equivalent)**

[image]

**Updated code**

```
convert = {"Undef" : 0, "C" : 1, "A" : 2, "B" : 3}
stage_converted = []
for i in df.stage :
    stage_converted.append(conversion[i])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.plot(df.time, stage_converted)

### Update ticks and labels for y-axis
ax.set_yticks( list(convert.values()) )
ax.set_yticklabels( list(convert.keys()) )

plt.show()
```

**...and finally the updated plot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input, I appreciate it. The order of the labels is now correct, but the plot doesn't look correct. I edited my question to show the plot before ordering the stages.

Comment: @Dreana - you have not provided the full data, so I used some dummy so as to extend the graph between 1-27 and 1-29. Obviously, the graphs will be different as the data is different. The question was on the ordering of the the `stage` column and that is what was addressed in the response. You will need to make the change and try it with your data and the new ordering is as needed

Comment: Of course, different data yield a different plot. What I meant is, that the whole style of the plot doesn't seem right anymore - in the first plot in the question it's visible, that there can only be one stage at a time, whereas in the second plot (using `sort_values`) the plot shows several stages at the same time, and that cannot be correct.

Comment: Hi @Dreana - You are right, the earlier code had an error. I have updated/corrected it. Just so it is clear I have added my data, the original plot, updated code and the final graph. Do note that, when the y-axis changes, the graph does change. Hope this is what you are looking for